# Mongodb server blacklisted Fatal Error

Tags: mongodb, database

I have created a web application for schools to send SMS, in angularjs, PHP and mongodb. For sending SMS to selected students by user application creates a separate background process for every selected student Applications sending about 1500 SMS at a time for knowing, it may grow to about 5000 in next 2-3 months The problem is our mongodb is start stoping unexpectedly since 3-4 days and we are unable to find a proper solution for it With error:

```
Fatal error with server black listed, mongodb
```

To solve this problem I have created a background process, which will check the status of mongodb in every 2 minutes if mongodb is not running then it will start the mongodb. But it is not the permanent solution i know

Any Suggetion?? why this is happenning

Comment: please provide more information. what are you running your mongodb instance on? have your tried googling the error?

Comment: i am running mongodb on aws ec2 t2.small  instance. yes i have tried googling it but i found nothing..

Comment: This actually sounds like a server configuration and/or networking issue more than anything else. You are likely to get more feedback on this from the folks at [serverfault.com](htps://serverfault.com) which is a related StackExchage site that specifically deals with questions on such issues. It certainly would appear to be a "SysAdmin" problem more than a "programming issue", which the other site is more suited to where StackOverflow is for programming based questions, and this appears not to be about such a topic.

Comment: ohhk. actually i did'nt know about [serverfault.com]. thanks @NeilLunn.  i will try there